# simplify reading from file with comma using extraction operator?

Tags: c++

I want to read from a file that consists of entries in each line that look like this:

```
BA,1355,SIN,3316,MEL,3339,Y,0,744
BA,1355,SIN,3316,LHR,507,,0,744 777
```

I want to store the first 6 columns and save them to string and int respectively.

At the moment, I have use `getline` to handle the comma, as shown below. But the drawbacks are 1) `getline` can only store things in string, so the numbers are saved as string instead of int 2) the code is repetitive

Is there a way that I can use the and `string::ignore` and `>>`  operator in `stringstream` to accomplish the same thing?  something like `linestream>> airline >> airlineNo >> scr >> scrNum >> det >>detNum;` where `airlineNo`, `scrNum`and `detNum` are numbers?

```
while (getline(myfile, temp)) {
        //std::cout<<temp<<std::endl;
        std::stringstream linestream(temp);
        std::string line;

        std::string airline, scr, det; 
        std::string airlineNo, scrNum, detNum;

        getline(linestream, airline, ',');
        getline(linestream, airlineNo, ',');
        getline(linestream, scr, ',');
        getline(linestream, scrNum, ',');
        getline(linestream, det, ',');
        getline(linestream, detNum, ',');
        
        std::cout<<scr<<" "<<det<<std::endl;
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure the first six fields are going to be filled, what you could do is replace every comma in a line to spaces, so that you can then use operator<< to get objects nicely. This doesn't work if any of the important fields are empty.

```
for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); ++i) {
    if (temp[i] == ',') temp[i] = ' ';
}
std::stringstream linestream(temp);
/*...*/
linestream >> airline >> airlineNo >> scr >> scrNum >> det >> detNum;
```

Comment: You can use [`std::replace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) instead of a manual loop: `std::replace(temp.begin(), temp.end(), ‘,’, ‘ ‘);`

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use `operator>>` with a `std::(i)stringstream`, eg:

```cpp
while (getline(myfile, temp)) {
    //std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    std::istringstream linestream(temp);

    std::string airline, scr, det; 
    int airlineNo, scrNum, detNum;

    getline(linestream, airline, ',');
    linestream >> airlineNo;
    linestream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',');
    getline(linestream, scr, ',');
    linestream >> scrNum;
    linestream.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), ',');
    getline(linestream, det, ',');
    linestream >> detNum;
        
    std::cout << scr << " " << det << std::endl;      
}
```

Alternatively, just use `std::stoi()` on the strings that `std::getline()` outputs, eg:

```cpp
while (getline(myfile, temp)) {
    //std::cout << temp << std::endl;
    std::istringstream linestream(temp);

    std::string airline, scr, det; 
    int airlineNo, scrNum, detNum;

    getline(linestream, airline, ',');
    getline(linestream, temp, ‘,’);
    airlineNo = std::stoi(temp);
    getline(linestream, scr, ',');
    getline(linestream, temp, ‘,’);
    scrNum = std::stoi(temp);
    getline(linestream, det, ',');
    getline(linestream, temp, ‘,’);
    detNum = std::stoi(temp);
        
    std::cout << scr << " " << det << std::endl;      
}
```

Comment: so basically use `getline` to read the string lines and `>>` or `stoi` to read the `int` lines. Cool!